# Doubt in the proof of Lemma 8.5 (chapter II) in Goerss & Jardine

Tags: homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff, model-categories

In Lemma 8.5 (chapter II) of Goerss & Jardine's book, we are given the following pushout square in a category of cofibrant objects:

$$\begin{array}{cc}
A & \xrightarrow {u} & B \\
\downarrow{i} & & \downarrow \\
C & \xrightarrow{u_*} & D
\end{array}$$

where $i$ is a cofibration and $u$ is a weak equivalence. The lemma claims that $u_*$ is a weak equivalence.

I did not understand the first and the last parts of the argument. At the start of the proof, they claim

> Trivial cofibrations are stable under pushouts, so Lemma 8.4 implies that it suffices to assume that there is a trivial cofibration $j:B\to A$ such that $u\cdot j=1_B$.

Lemma 8.4 claims that any map in a category of cofibrant objects can be factorised into a cofibration and a weak equivalence that is left inverse to a trivial cofibration.

I am unable to see how lemma $8.4$ can be used to assume that $u\cdot j= 1_B$.

I don't understand the last paragraph of the proof as well (where the authors switch to a slice category). Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The cited lemma also implies that any weak equivalences can be factored as a trivial cofibration followed by a weak equivalence that is left inverse to a trivial cofibration. The pushout of a composite is the composite of the pushouts so we may reduce to the case in question.

Comment: Are you using a different copy than me? You are referencing lemma 9.4 and 9.5 I believe.

Comment: @NoelLundström: I am using 1999 reprint published by Birkhäuser.

Comment: @ZhenLin: Thank you for the comment. I understand it now. If you wrote it as an answer,  I can 'tick' it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cited lemma implies $u : A \to B$ can be factored as a trivial cofibration $a : A \to A'$ followed by a weak equivalence $u' : A \to B$ that is left inverse to a trivial cofibration $j' : B' \to A$. The pushout of a composite is the composite of the pushouts, and we already know that the pushout of a (trivial) cofibration is a (trivial) cofibration, so we may reduce to the case where $u : A \to B$ itself is left inverse to a trivial cofibration.